# Notify when property change on Ebean's models in PlayFramework?

Tags: playframework-2.0, listener, ebean

I'd like to add in an History model all the changes events occurred to a specific model, for that, here's what I did :

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    @Id
    private Long Id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        History.add(this.getId(), "name", this.name, name);
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class History extends Model {
    public Long beanId;
    public String field;
    public String oldValue;
    public String newValue;

    public static void add (Long beanId, String field, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        History history = new History();
        history.beanId = beanId;
        history.field = field;
        history.oldValue = oldValue;
        history.newValue = newValue;
        history.save();
    }
}
```

Everything would work perfectly except beanId is not saved. The reason is clear for me, but because of this, I'm stuck.

The reason ?
It's because I set those values via Form in my controller (in the update method) :

```
Form<MyModel> form = form(MyModel.class).bindFromRequest();
MyModel model = form.get();
```

By doing this, `bindFromRequest()` set the values in MyModel without setting the id (of course), so `this.getId()` is null.

How can I do to have `getId()` having the corresponding ID of the model ?

(note: I simplified the problem, removing the create, the checks, etc).

Comment: I might be missing something, but: if you don't have the id, whare are you supposed to get it? Are the `name`s of all `MyModel`s unique? Otherwise, how would you know which entry you are working on without passing the id somehow?

Comment: You could also be interested in the `BeanPersistListener` http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/event/BeanPersistListener.html

Comment: That's why I need the ID and I don't have it because of form().bindFromRequest() ! :)

Comment: BeanPersistListener is interesting, but I can't find an example of implementation, do you have a link?

Comment: As a follow up, a solution can be found in the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847063/playframework-how-to-register-a-beanpersistlistener

Comment: But I face a new problem : Using the form(), the oldValue & newValue in the bean are the same (but really, they aren't) ...