# PlayFramework, how to register a BeanPersistListener?

Tags: playframework-2.0, listener, ebean

I discovered the [BeanPersistListener](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/event/BeanPersistListener.html) that I'd like to register to some of my models, but I didn't find any documentation, from Ebean nor PlayFramework on how to integrate it.

From the documentation :

> A BeanPersistListener is either found automatically via class path search or can be added programmatically via ServerConfiguration.addEntity().

Apparently, it isn't found automatically (I added some `Logger.info` in the implemented methods, and nothing was shown), so I'd like to add it via ServerConfiguration, but how? where?

I'm also suspecting it's a version problem. From what I've seen, BeanPersistListener is from Ebean 2.6.0, but I can't find which version of Ebean PlayFramework is running (I'm using 2.0.4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Play 2.0.4 uses Ebean version 2.7.3 [[1]](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.0.4/framework/project/Build.scala#L196)

And for registering your listener, you could try to use a ServerConfigStartup as shown in this [documentation](http://play2-docs-snapshot.herokuapp.com/render/JavaEbean):

```
package models;

import com.avaje.ebean.config.ServerConfig;
import com.avaje.ebean.event.ServerConfigStartup;
import com.avaje.ebean.event.BeanPersistListener;

public class MyServerConfigStartup implements ServerConfigStartup {
    @Override
    public void onStart(ServerConfig serverConfig) {
        serverConfig.add(new BeanPersistListener() {
            ....
        });
    }
}
```

I never tested it, I think it is worth a try :-)

**Update from comments:**

You'll need to put these classes under the `models` package or a child of the `models`  package so that Ebean can find them.

Comment: Awesome! +1 for the Ebean version and the link. I'll try and accept your answer then (or comment if I can't make it works)

Comment: Soooo I added your code. Funny things, it is only executed on the models package (I first added it at some place else). I know because I added some Logger.info to indicate which Models have been registered for listening. On my Listener class, I added Logger.info too in each implemented method. But whatever I call (inserted/updated/deleted), nothing is logged, so there aren't called. Any idea why ?

Comment: That's it! I know why : You need to put the listener AND The ConfigStartup class in the `models` package (or a child of the `models` package, **including** the listener !). It works now :)

Comment: Good news !! I'll update my answer with your comments for the next readers !

Answer (score 0):

I see a two problems with BeanPersistListener in PLay Framework:

1. I must create for every entity own BeanPersistListener. Not nice when I have 100 enities.
2. BeanPersistListener is fired in background thread. I have no information who was user.